# How to convert a complex javascript object to string and back

Tags: javascript, string, object, serialization

I have an object that contains arrays which is made up of other arrays it also contains methods. The problem that i am facing is that i can't use JSon because of the multidimensional arrays and the methods.

The reason i want to convert it to a string is to store into the Iphone's 
localStorage.

you can only store text inside of there and i was hoping for a way to store a complex object about a user as a string and able to deserialize it again after. Is there even a way to do this. I don't know javascript well enough to write my own api. That was the option i started to try and look into at this point :(

Comment: JSON can encode multi-dimensional arrays, but not methods.

Comment: can't you just save the .js script and then attempt to eval() it at runtime ? But I don't know if you can actually read and execute from local storage.

Comment: Why do you want to persist your methods?

Comment: Im coming from c++ took a course on it so in my mind keeping the object as one made sense. i guess i could just move methods outside the object it's self. I do use Jquery. I wanted to persist them so that when i reconstruct the object. i can perform the various methods. some methods are to update the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize it to JSON. You can serialize / deserialize complex objects and arrays.

There is no way you can serialize methods (code).

For local storage persistence I would recommend [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/).

Comment: @mplungjan yes, because `alert()` does an implicit `.toString()` on each argument.  The JSON serialiser will refuse to do so.

Comment: So we can add it ourselves, no?

Comment: @mplungjan - but why do you want to persist methods in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

no need to store in localStorage you can use global array any where in your application  try this once

Comment: no i need the localStorage so they can exit and come back to it later. the object contains alot of things

Answer (score 0):

It's normally possible to serialise a method using `myfunc.toString()`

So, you *could* use a `replacer` function in `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to recognise methods, and call `.toString()` on them, and them somehow recognise them on parsing and turn them back into first class functions.

However - note that a reconstructed function will not have access to the original object's scope, i.e. private variables, or methods, etc.

e.g.

```
function A() {
    var foo = 'bar';
    this.test = function test() { console.log(foo) };
};

var b = new A();
var f = b.test.toString();  // the text of the method
b.test2 = new Function(f);

b.test2();
> undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

well,
there is a way to convert object with functions to string and vise verse. take a look at this plugin:

http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/

good luck,

-Vadim